# JavaScript -- reading a table

Tags: javascript

This is a function that, when passed a table as an argument, applies a different style color to alternating rows to improve readability. i.e. first row is dark grey, second row is light grow, third row is dark grey etc.

As mentioned, it gets passed the whole table as an argument. None of the rows have ids.  Starting at this line  `var aTBODY = oTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody");`, I understand what is happening. Namely, it gets the table body and then all the rows within it and stripes them alternately.

1) But what is happening exactly in the first five lines of the program? The comments don't explain it clearly for me.

2) does looping over a table length (i.e idArray.length) create an array of rows? what is happening with var id = idArray[indx]; ?

3) When it says, in the comments, `get the table that corresponds to this id`, using the code `var oTable = document.getElementById(id)` why is this a necessary step? what is happening?

thank you if you can explain

```
function createStripedTable(idArray) {
    // for each table ID that we're given, stripe all the rows.
    for (var indx = 0; indx < idArray.length; indx++) {
        var id = idArray[indx];
        // get the table that corresponds to this ID
        var oTable = document.getElementById(id);
        if (oTable == null) 
            return;

        // get its table body, which contains all the TR tags
        var aTBODY = oTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody");

        // set the CSS class for each one of the TR tags 
        for (var i = 0; i < aTBODY.length; i++) {
            // get an array of all the TR tags in the TBODY
            var aTR = aTBODY[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (var j = 0; j < aTR.length; j++) {  
                // the % operator divides the given number by another
                // and returns the remainder. This is how we alternate the
                // rows. 
                aTR[j].className = (j % 2 == 1) ? "stripe1" : "stripe2";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code that's calling it.

```
function() {createStripedTable(new Array("MSFTQuotes"))
```

Here's an excerpt of the one and only one table that is passed.

```
<body>
    <table id="MSFTQuotes">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="7" align="center">
                    <span class="TableTitle">Stock Activity for Aug 5, 2008 - Nov 5, 2008 </span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="center" width="14%">
                    <div align="right" class="style5">
                        Date</div>
                </th>
                <th align="center" width="14%">
                    <div align="right" class="style5">
                        Open</div>
                </th>
                <th align="center" width="14%">
                    <div align="right" class="style5">
                        High</div>
                </th>
                <th align="center" width="14%">
                    <div align="right" class="style5">
                        Low</div>
                </th>
                <th align="center" width="14%">
                    <div align="right" class="style5">
                        Close</div>
                </th>
                <th align="center" width="14%">
                    <div align="right" class="style5">
                        Volume</div>
                </th>
                <th align="center" width="14%">
                    <div align="right" class="style5">
                        Adj Close</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    5-Nov-08
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    29.21
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    29.36
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    29.03
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    29.31
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    95,337,696
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    29.31
                </td>
```

Comment: An array of table is getting passed in the argument and not the table Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function accepts an array of `id` values corresponding to `table` elements. It loops through those IDs and does its striping work on all of the `tbody` elements within the tables.

Somewhat more annotated (see `TJC:`s):

```
function createStripedTable(idArray) {
    // for each table ID that we're given, stripe all the rows.
    // TJC: Loop through all of the IDs in the given array
    for (var indx = 0; indx < idArray.length; indx++) {
        // TJC: Get the ID value for index `indx` in the array
        var id = idArray[indx];
        // get the table that corresponds to this ID
        var oTable = document.getElementById(id);
        if (oTable == null) // TJC: Invalid ID, ignore it
            return;

        // get its table body, which contains all the TR tags
        // TJC: Get the `tbody`s under the table. One table
        // can have multiple `tbody` elements.
        var aTBODY = oTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody");

        // set the CSS class for each one of the TR tags 
        for (var i = 0; i < aTBODY.length; i++) {
            // get an array of all the TR tags in the TBODY
            // TJC: It's actually a NodeList, but you can largely
            // treat it as an array
            var aTR = aTBODY[i].getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (var j = 0; j < aTR.length; j++) {  
                // the % operator divides the given number by another
                // and returns the remainder. This is how we alternate the
                // rows. 
                    aTR[j].className = (j % 2 == 1) ? "stripe1" : "stripe2";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The good news is that [IE9 finally supports](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) the [`nth-child` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), so someday you'll be able to stop doing this with code.

Comment: thank you. but in the example given in the tutorial, there is only one table passed and the table that is passed only has one "id," which is the id for the whole table. so when it loops through that id, what is it actually looping through? I don't see how this is consistent with your statement that the function "accepts an array of id values corresponding to table elements".  If you can explain more please do. I'm a bit of a newbie. Cheers

Comment: @Michael: If you quote the code where it's being passed in, I can tell you. ;-) It's clearly dealing with an array, though. Could it be that the code looks like this: `createStripedTable(["theTableId"]);`? That's creating a single-element array and passing it into the function. And of course, it's always possible that there's an error in whatever tutorial you're dealing with, where they updated how the function works but forgot to update where they call it. That kind of thing happens all the time.

Comment: o.k, I posted the function call. You're right it is an array being passed in. So those first few lines seem superfluous in this example, which is why I tried to run the code starting from when it getElementByTag("tbody"), but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Michael: You can try it out on JSBin.com: This fails, just passing in the ID: http://jsbin.com/egaji5 but this works, passing in an array containing the ID: http://jsbin.com/egaji5/2

Comment: @Michael: (Overlapping comments) Yeah, I thought it probably was. It's using the really verbose way of doing it, though. Look at the jsbin links above for a better way. Not my only issue with that sample code, btw. :-) If you're looking at it as a tutorial for using their API for something, great, but if you're using it as a JavaScript tutorial, I'd look elsewhere. Best,

Answer (score 1):

`idArray` is an array of all IDS for more than one table.  This function will change the alternate rows for each of the tables whose id is in idArray.

The outer loop is iterating through ids.  The first five lines inside the loop are assuming they are ids of tables, and fetching the contents of the table element corresponding to each ID.

The next five lines in the loop then fetch the table body contents and change the css class of alternate rows.

Comment: but in the example given in the tutorial, there is only one table passed, the table that is passed only has one "id," which is the id for the whole table. so when it loops through that id, what is it actually looping through?

Comment: can you paste code from the example.  It is likely that if it is structured the way you are describing it, then the example is wrong.  Either that or the single table id is being passed as an array i.e. an array of just one element, which this will still work for.

Comment: O.k, I pasted some of the html. You are correct that an array is being passed, but an array with only one element is being passed, then shouldn't I be able to comment out the first lines up to the return since only one element is in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines before the first `for` loop in the code

```
var tabarray=new Array();
tabarray.push(thetableidYoupassed);
idArray=tabArray
```

'thetableidYoupassed' is the actual argument with which you called the function 'createStripedTable'

Keep the rest of the code as it is...This should work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Your method accepts an array of table IDs. So all the tables need to have IDs.

```
function createStripedTable(idArray) { //idArray is an array of table IDs
```

Then it loops through them and gets the ID one by one

```
for (var indx = 0; indx < idArray.length; indx++) {
        var id = idArray[indx]; //this is the ID of a table
```

Then it checks whether the table actually exists in the DOM or not

```
var oTable = document.getElementById(id); //IF the table with a matching ID is not found, you get NULL
        if (oTable == null) 
            return; //no table that matches the ID? return
```

Ideally, that line should be `continue` or something similar. Because in this instance. If you pass your method an array like `['table1', 'table2', 'faketable', 'table3']`, your method won't strip `table3` because it never gets there in the array (because of the `return`)

Comment: but the problem is, in the example given, only one table is passed, and it only has one "id," which is the id for the whole table. So it's not looping through an array of tables, or rather if it is an array with one element. If only one table is passed, then everything up to the first return should not be necessary but when I commented it out, the stripes no longer appeared.

Comment: One thing it doesnt check is whether the element represented by the ID is actually a table.